# how to insert a link to a local file into a markdown cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Dear ipython notebook users,

I want to insert a link to a local file located in the notebook directory, and no, it is not an image (the only example I've found). I want to insert this link within a markdown cell.

When clicked on the link, the file is to be opened with a local application (in this case, a molecule viewer)

I've tried to come up with the correct syntax, but no luck. Please, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I want to insert a link to a local file located in the notebook directory
>
> I want to insert this link within a markdown cell.

The path need to be relative to where the **server** has been started, and prefixed with `files/`.
e.g: `[my molecule](files/molecules/ethanol.mol)`

> the file is to be opened with a local application (in this case, a molecule viewer)

Not possible unless your application support custom links protocol like the `itunes://` or `apt-get://` one. the best that can append is that on link click you will be prompted to download the file. (keep in mind that the server can be on a different machine thant your browser)

Comment: Wow, it did the trick! [waterBox30.pdb](files/waterBox30.pdb) produced the link I wanted. When clicked, Firefox launched the molecule viewer (I had previously instructed Firefox to associate the viewer with the .pdb extension). Thanks a million!

Comment: it did not work for me:
the link shown in the address: http://127.0.0.1:8888/file/memberships.pdf

Comment: @moldovean I had the same problem, by putting just the filename (and path, relative to the server) and omitting 'file/', I managed to get it to work

Comment: Note that the path you put in the link should be relative to the __notebook location__, not the server root. If the notebook is in the servers root folder, there's no difference though.

Comment: For me, certain special characters like "(" or ")" may brake the file/page path and lead to the link not working. I fixed it by replacing them with the code equivalents found here and then everything worked. http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: Any idea on how to pass remote files to a link? *(e.g. \\server\path\file)*

Comment: This was very helpful; though, I had to make one slight modification. I had to add a `/` before `files`. **Example:** `[my molecule](/files/molecules/ethanol.mol)`

Answer (score 11):

completenting the answer of Matt, it will work only in you import FileLink

```
from IPython.display import FileLink, FileLinks
FileLink('path_to_file/filename.extension')
```

Then in a markdown cell insert your links waterBox30.pdb

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer is not working for me. The following worked fine:

If the file is in the same folder where the server has been started:

```
 [<some name>](./<file name>.<extension>)
```

If it's in another folder, let's say in the folder Data:

```
 [<some name>](../data/<file name>.<extension>)
```